# Use jQuery to convert JSON array to HTML bulleted list

Tags: jquery, json

How can you convert an array of strings represented in JSON format and convert this to an HTML bulleted list using jQuery?

Comment: Can you add an example of your JSON structure?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @Switz, getJSON is how I will get the data - not clear on how to convert one of the arrays into a list

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806047/distributing-json-array-output-to-each-li

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo('body');
var json = { items: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'] };
$(json.items).each(function(index, item) {
    ul.append(
        $(document.createElement('li')).text(item)
    );
});
```

As far as fetching the JSON from your server using AJAX is concerned you could use the [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kAT8a/).

Comment: I've never seen jsfiddle.net before.  I approve.

Comment: @climbage, it's a very good site allowing fast javascript mockups supporting popular frameworks.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

// Here is the code I use.  You should be able to adapt it to your needs.

function process_test_json() {
  var jsonDataArr = { "Errors":[],"Success":true,"Data":{"step0":{"collectionNameStr":"ideas_org_Private","url_root":"http:\/\/192.168.1.128:8500\/ideas_org\/","collectionPathStr":"C:\\ColdFusion8\\wwwroot\\ideas_org\\wwwrootchapter0-2\\verity_collections\\","writeVerityLastFileNameStr":"C:\\ColdFusion8\\wwwroot\\ideas_org\\wwwroot\\chapter0-2\\LastFileName.txt","doneFlag":false,"state_dbrec":{},"errorMsgStr":"","fileroot":"C:\\ColdFusion8\\wwwroot\\ideas_org\\wwwroot"}}};

var htmlStr= "<h3 class='recurse_title'>[jsonDataArr] struct is</h3> " + recurse( jsonDataArr );
alert( htmlStr );
$( document.createElement('div') ).attr( "class", "main_div").html( htmlStr ).appendTo('div#out');
$("div#outAsHtml").text( $("div#out").html() ); 
}
function recurse( data ) {
  var htmlRetStr = "<ul class='recurseObj' >"; 
  for (var key in data) {
        if (typeof(data[key])== 'object' && data[key] != null) {
            htmlRetStr += "<li class='keyObj' ><strong>" + key + ":</strong><ul class='recurseSubObj' >";
            htmlRetStr += recurse( data[key] );
            htmlRetStr += '</ul  ></li   >';
        } else {
            htmlRetStr += ("<li class='keyStr' ><strong>" + key + ': </strong>&quot;' + data[key] + '&quot;</li  >' );
        }
  };
  htmlRetStr += '</ul >';    
  return( htmlRetStr );
}

</script>
</head><body>
<button onclick="process_test_json()" >Run process_test_json()</button>
<div id="out"></div>
<div id="outAsHtml"></div>
</body>

<!-- QUESTION: Maybe some one with more jquery experience 
could convert this to a shorter / pure jquery method -->
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the recursion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A JSON string like that would look like:

```
'["foo","bar","base","ball"]'
```

You can parse that into an Javascript array object by calling `JSON.parse()`, iterate over that array and insert the strings.

```
var jsonstring = '["foo","bar","base","ball"]',
    arr = JSON.parse(jsonstring),
    len = arr.length;

while(len--) {
    $('<li>', { 
        text:   arr[len]
    }).appendTo('ul');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery jPut plugin. Just create a html template & call your json file. you can also call the ajax file through jPut (ajax_url)

http://plugins.jquery.com/jput/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var json = [{"name": "item1","link":"link1"},{"name": "item2","link":"link2"}];

          //jPut code 
          $("#menu").jPut({
            jsonData:json,
            name:"template",
          });
    });
</script>

<body>    
        <!-- jput template, the li that you want to append to ul-->
        <div jput="template">
           <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/{{link}}">{{name}}</a></li>
        </div>

        <!-- your main ul -->
        <ul id="menu">
        </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: `jput` is not a valid  attribute.

Comment: @Benio Add jput.js in your HTML.

Comment: `jput`, as you show in example code, is not a valid attribute. If you want to use custom attribute, you should use [a custom data attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes), like `data-jput`, otherwise it's not a valid HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

If your json strings are in stringArr:

```
$.each(stringArr, function(idx, val) {
   $('<li></li>').html(val);
}
```

or something among these lines should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?  I haven't tested it, but it should work.

```
ul = $("<ul/>");
$(json_arr).each(function(){
    $("<li/>").text(this).appendTo(ul);
});

// add ul to DOM
```