# How to convert JSON to HTML Drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my JSON Code

```
data = {
    "master_item":{
        "M5":{
            "PMBLT000164":"PMBLT000164"
        },
        "M8":{
            "PMBTN000020":"PMBTN000020"
        },
        "M165":{
            "PMBTN000003":"PMBTN000003","PMBTN000004":"PMBTN000004","PMBTN000006":"PMBTN000006","PMBTN000009":"PMBTN000009"
        }
    },
    "products":{
        "PMBTN000003":"PMBTN000003","PMBTN000002":"PMBTN000002"
    },
    "bulk":{
        "BBTPB000003":"BBTPB000003","BMBCT000002":"BMBCT000002"
    }
}
```

What I want this i have to convert this into three dropdown menu

```
<select name='master_item'>
 <optgroup label="M5">
<option value="PMBLT000164">PMBLT000164</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Above HTML is based on json data.

**EDIT:**

I have tried following code in JQUERY

```
var options = $("#options");
    $.each(data.master_item, function(i,a) {
    options.append($("<option />").val(a).text(a));
});
```

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Sorry i have added now.

Comment: The same logic mentioned in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189365/use-jquery-to-convert-json-array-to-html-bulleted-list) should be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a function check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvQuj/2/). The advantage of this over the other solutions: data can contain as much nested levels as you want..

```
var options = $("<select/>"),
    addOptions = function(opts, container){
        $.each(opts, function(i, opt) {
            if(typeof(opt)=='string'){
                container.append($("<option />").val(opt).text(opt));
            } else {
                var optgr = $("<optgroup />").attr('label',i);
                addOptions(opt, optgr)
                container.append(optgr);
            }
        });
    };

addOptions(data,options); // or addOptions(data.master_item,options);
$('body').append(options);
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose it can be done with something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8hyaL/):

```
var $select = $('<select>').attr({
    name: 'master_item'
});

$.each(data.master_item, function(optGroupLabel, options) {
    var $optGroup = $('<optgroup>').attr({
        label: optGroupLabel
    });
    $.each(options, function(optionKey, optionValue) {
        var $option = $('<option>').attr({
            value: optionValue
        }).text(optionValue);
        $optGroup.append($option);
    });
    $select.append($optGroup);
});

$('body').append($select);
```

Basically, it's a two-step process, and at each step we go deeper in the data structure. At the first level we process optgroup, at the second - options within each optgroup.

*I have used hashes in* `.attr` *to simplify adding more attributes. Another important point is to append the whole structure to the DOM only after it will be completed.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea, but I think you should just use a for loop:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenmtwhunt/ua7jw/

Comment: Please avoid posting link only answers.  Your post will be more valuable if you copy your code directly into the answer body.  1. Researchers won't need to link chase. 2. Stackoverflow provides runnable snippet functionality for js. 3. If the external link is ever changed or removed, your answer will be worthless to researchers.