# Group JSON using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

This is my code

```
<?php
$something = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $something[] = $row;
} 
mysql_close($con);
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    some= <?php echo json_encode($something); ?>; 
</script>
```

The above code will generate:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Ray","author":"Ray","thumb":"some source","views":"10000"}]
```

But I want to generate a json string like this:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Ray","author":"Ray","image":{"cls":"image","thumb":"some source","views":"10000"}}]
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode` encodes whatever object structure you have. If you want certain properties to be as sub-object, you have to create such object in memory..

For instance, if you had

```
$a = array("id"=>1, 
           "title"=>"Ray", 
           "image" => 
               array(
                 "thumb"=>"some source",
                 "cls"=>"image"
                )
           );
```

it would encode in json in a similar way you are mentioning.

This means that you have to loop through mysql results and create the new structure before. Then call json_encode on it.

Comment: Nice explanation, Thanks.. Can you tell me how can i convert json into html using jquery?

Comment: You will find some interesting ideas in this StackOverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189365/use-jquery-to-convert-json-array-to-html-bulleted-list

Comment: Thanks, Even am too seeing that.