# JavaScript to categorize array elements and output as HTML

Tags: javascript

we have an array of the format `bugs = ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10']`.

You can see it has 4 different bug types/tokens (BD, SSNC, RI and RC) - this could expand in future. The token and ID Number separator can be a '-' or '/' or nothing (E.g: regexp match[-/]?) ie, the array can be

```
= ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10'] or
= ['BD-2', 'SSNC/1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC/10'] or
= ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC3', 'RI-2', 'RC10']
```

Now trying to build a Simple JavaScript function which can categorize the elements into separate arrays based on token type and then output a simple HTML table with bugtoken type as column headers.

For an array of `bugs = ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10']`.`

Output should look like:

```
 ___________________________________
| BD      SSNC        RI      RC    |
|------+---------+--------+---------+
|BD-2  | SSNC-1, |   RI-2 |  RC-10  |
|      | SSNC-3  |        |         |
|______|_________|________|_________|
```

Comment: What do you do with ID?

Comment: how should categorized array look like?

Comment: Updated the question to clarify output format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use an object for grouping with the matched identifier.

```js
var data = ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10', 'BD-2', 'SSNC/1', 'SSNC/3', 'RI/1', 'RC/10', 'BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC3', 'RI-2', 'RC10'],
    grouped = function (data) {
        var o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var group = a.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+/);
            o[group] = o[group] || [];
            o[group].push(a);
        });
        return o;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Update, result with distinct token and id.

```js
var data = ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10', 'BD-2', 'SSNC/1', 'SSNC/3', 'RI/1', 'RC/10', 'BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC3', 'RI-2', 'RC10'],
    grouped = function (data) {
        var o = {}, r = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var group = a.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+/),
                number = a.match(/\d+$/);
            o[group] = o[group] || {};
            r[group] = r[group] || [];
            if (!(number in o[group])) {
                o[group][number] = r[group].push(a) - 1;
            }
            if (r[group][o[group][number]] !== a) {
                r[group][o[group][number]] = group + '-' + number;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Much more elegant than mine :)

Comment: nice logic.. can we add the duplicate filter, for example BD-2 is repeated

Comment: and what is with values like `SSNC-1` and `SSNC/1`? are they equal?

Comment: Good point, yes they are equal just that the inputter did not follow the right delimiter.. so they should be filtered as well.

Comment: and what should be the wanted style, non character, `-` or `/`?

Comment: if the bud ID has duplicates like SSNC/1, SSNC-1, SSNC1, we need to pick only one and use - as delimiter

Answer (score 1):

```
bugs = ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10'];

sortedBugs = [];

bugs.forEach(function(bug){
    match = bug.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)[ -/]{1}.*/);

    if(!sortedBugs[match[1]])
        sortedBugs[match[1]] = new Set();

    sortedBugs[match[1]].add(match[0]);
});

for(var x in sortedBugs)
{
    console.log("Bug Category '" + x + "':");

    sortedBugs[x].forEach(function(a) {console.log(a);});
}
```

Now, sortedBugs has four entries, each of which contains an array of the corresponding bugs. So, sortedBugs['BD'] has only 'BD-2', while sortedBugs['SSNC'] has 'SSNC-1' and 'SSNC-3'.

Edit: Four very similar solution, nices. :D

Another edit: now has no duplicate entries anymore by using a set

Comment: Works perfect. just that duplicates are not filtered out. for example if the array has duplicates of the same token type, we need to be able to skip that.. eg: bugs = ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10','BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10'];

Comment: You are right. This can easily be solved by using (new Set(sortedBugs[x])) instead of sortedBugs[x]. You can also use (new Set(sortedBugs[x])).forEach(.) etc. :)

Comment: Can we filter duplicates in sortedBugs array generation itself?

Comment: Yes. I have changed the code above and we just use a set now in the first instance.

Comment: Logic is failing if the token and number has no seperator. eg: SSNC1. regexp needed the following change: match = bug.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)[-/]?.*/);

Comment: This will work, unless there is another a-zA-Z letter followed after SSNC. If there are only numbers, your regex is better, though, right. Do not forget to mark any answer as solution, when you consider your question answered, so that it will disappear as unanswered question at stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that token name can have only alphabets (or numbers followed by alphabets like 2BD)

try

```
var array = ['BD-2', 'SSNC-1', 'SSNC-3', 'RI-2', 'RC-10'];
var output = {};
array.forEach( function(value){ 

   var number = (value.match( /\d+/g)).pop(); 
   token = value.substring( 0, value.length - ( number.length ) ).replace(/[\W]/g,"");
   if ( !output[token] )
   {
      output[token] = [];
   }
   if ( output[token].indexOf( value ) == -1 )
   {
       output[token].push( value );
   } 
} );

console.table( output );
```

Comment: thanks, this works but includes only numbers in output array but we need the complete bugID with number

Comment: @sudheerg Check now, added whole value in the output

Comment: works well, just that we need duplicate filter and HTML output in table format

Comment: @sudheerg removed duplicates, check now

Comment: @sudheerg as far as tabular format is concerned, there are various examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395976/how-to-display-a-json-array-in-table-format, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393860/how-to-parse-a-json-list-like-this-and-display-its-elements-in-html

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered but I have a different solution I would like to share.

I recently created a library that does array categorization in JavaScript, called [`categorize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/categorize).

Here is what would be the solution using it:

```
const { categorize } = require("categorize");

const bugTypes = ["BD", "SSNC", "RI", "RC"];

const bugs = ["BD-2", "SSNC-1", "SSNC-3", "RI-2", "RC-10"];

const bugsCategorized = categorize(bugs, bugTypes.map((bugType) => ({
  name: bugType,
  filter: (bug) => bug.startsWith(bugType)
})));
```

The `bugsCategorized` variable will contain this object:

```
{
  "BD": [
    "BD-2"
  ],
  "SSNC": [
    "SSNC-1",
    "SSNC-3"
  ],
  "RI": [
    "RI-2"
  ],
  "RC": [
    "RC-10"
  ]
}
```