# How to display data using WEB APIi?

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I want to fetch data from an SQL database table and display it in an HTML table using Web API and Ajax.

Here is my controller method:

```
public class userLoginController : ApiController{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=(local); initial catalog=TestDB; integrated security=true");
    [HttpGet]
    public void GetRecord(Login l){
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from logintable", con);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //ad.Fill(ds);
        List<Login> list = new List<Login>(){
            new Login(){},
        };
    }
}
```

My model contains a name and a password property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a Json list like this and display its elements in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393860/how-to-parse-a-json-list-like-this-and-display-its-elements-in-html)

Comment: shouldn't it be IEnumberable<Login> Get(){ blah blah blah return list;}

Comment: why did you post an image of your code instead of just your code?